# not able to find class in spark package HBaseContext

Tags: apache-spark, hbase

I am trying to use "HBaseContext" through spark but not able fine any details all the details coming blank

[https://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/spark/example/hbasecontext/][1]

I am trying to implement some method explained here
http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2015/08/apache-spark-comes-to-apache-hbase-with-hbase-spark-module/

can anyone help who has implemented any of these

Comment: it might assist to find out which version you are using? Also please provide a code snippet of what you have tried.

Answer (score 6):

Although HBaseContext already implemented and documented in HBase Reference Guide, but the author/the community has not release it yet, you can see from this link [HBaseContext Commit History](https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=hbase.git;a=history;f=hbase-spark/src/main/scala/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/spark/HBaseContext.scala;h=a9b38ba6e4a94485b14806751a1c8c733431307e;hb=refs/heads/master), the community is still working on it recently(there is no update for project [SparkOnHBase](https://github.com/cloudera-labs/SparkOnHBase) for a long time), and for any download version of HBase, hbase-spark module is not included at all.

This is a big confusion for beginners, hope the community can improve it, to access HBase from Spark RDD, you can consider it as normal Hadoop DataSource, HBase does provide TableInputFormat and TableOutputFormat for this purpose.